# Using Googe Search form on checkout page with HTTPS

Tags: magento-1, catalogsearch

I am running Magento, with Google Search - and its setup in the header of every page and works perfectly, except on the one page checkout page - because its an SSL page, and the search box sends results to an unsecure page. I need to make the code send the results to a secure page. This is the code in `form.mini.phtml` that sends:

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl( searchresults ) ?>" method="get">
```

Its calling for page "Searchresults". How can i get it to call the HTTPS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer finally - you need to add a secure array to the form id, as follows:

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('searchresults',array('_secure'=>true)); ?>" method="get">
```